# Button in popup does not fire event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, devexpress

```
<dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl1" runat="server">
     <dx:ASPxPanel ID="Panel1" runat="server"
         <dx:ASPxGridView ID="PopUpGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/DevEx/{0}/styles.css"
               CssPostfix="DevEx" DataSourceID="CustomerBilgi" KeyFieldName="ID" ClientInstanceName="PopUpGrid">
                   <Columns>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
                        <ClearFilterButton Visible="true" />
                        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID" VisibleIndex="1" />
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CODE" VisibleIndex="2" />
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="NAME" VisibleIndex="3" />
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CREATE_DATE" VisibleIndex="4" />
                        </Columns>
                        <Settings ShowFilterRow="true" />
                        <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="true" />
                        <SettingsBehavior AllowSelectByRowClick="true" />
            </dx:ASPxGridView>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                          <dx:ASPxButton ID="ButtonPopUp" Text="Ok" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonPopUp_Click"
                                                Width="200px" AutoPostBack="true">
                          </dx:ASPxButton>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
             <asp:EntityDataSource ID="CustomerBilgi" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=IntranETEntities"
                                        DefaultContainerName="IntranETEntities" EnableFlattening="False"
                                        EntitySetName="CUSTOMERs" EntityTypeFilter="CUSTOMER" Select="it.[ID],it.[CODE], it.[NAME], it.[CREATE_DATE]">
                                    </asp:EntityDataSource> ....
        </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
```

In pop up I have Grid and a button. In server side the button the below event exist

```
 protected void ButtonPopUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   ....  }
```

When I debugged the code I see that the even is not fired. Is there anything that I did wrong ? How can i fix it ? I'm using EntityFramework and Devexpress.
Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a table start and end tag? Also, does the postback fire if you use a normal <asp:Button /> ?

Comment: I solved my problem. I'm supposed to give validation group in properties. That was the problem. 
Thanks for reply @MikeyMouse